# How to change text of UIButton via fetched data from Parse after event

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

So I have 2 like buttons: one is an outlet, and the other is an action. I did this because I wanted to change the text for one of them, and to trigger a function that increments the count for the other. When the user taps the "like button," the like button sends it's incremental count to Parse and should increment the number of likes. But for some reason, I can send its new count (number of likes) to Parse, but it won't change the text of the button. Here is my code:

```
        @IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func likeButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if (parseObject != nil) {
        if var likes: Int? = parseObject!.objectForKey("numberOfLikes") as? Int {
            let newNumberOfLikes = likes! + 1
            parseObject!.setObject(newNumberOfLikes, forKey: "numberOfLikes")
            parseObject!.saveInBackground()

            likeButton.setTitle("\(newNumberOfLikes) likes", forState: UIControlState.Selected)
        }
    }

    // THIS WORKS
    unlikeButton?.hidden = false
    unlikeButton?.alpha = 1.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
        self.unlikeButton?.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: {
            (value: Bool) in self.unlikeButton?.hidden = false
    })
```

Comment: I have to have a look, but I would have thought you want to change the title for UIControlState.**Normal**...?

Comment: Changing to UIControlState.Selected to .Normal doesn't work either.

Comment: I think a reason might be having to refresh the data automatically. It only chages the number when I "pull to refresh."

Answer (score 0):

Due to the same name of like button outlet and button action(**likeButton**)

Try to change any one of the name else follow below

```
@IBAction func likeButton(sender: UIButton) {

  sender.setTitle("\(newNumberOfLikes) likes", forState: .Normal)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing

```
likeButton.setTitle("\(newNumberOfLikes) likes", forState: UIControlState.Selected)
```

to

```
likeButton.setTitle("\(newNumberOfLikes) likes", forState: .Normal)
```